# add school logo to education section

Tags: graphics, cv, resume, logos

I want to add my school logo to the education section.
This is the Overleaf template I'm using.
https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/a-customised-curve-cv/mvmbhkwsnmwv

I tried adding \includegraphics in the education.tex file.

```
\begin{rubric}{Education}

\entry*[2009 -- 2013]%
    \textbf{Ph.D., Unseen University} High Energy Magic.
    \par Thesis title: \emph{Low-Cost Mana Generation in Under-Resouced Evironments.}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{photo.jpg}
%
\entry*[2003 -- 2006]%
    \textbf{M.Sc.~Computer Science, Unseen} in High Energy Magic.\par
    Thesis title: \emph{Applying ant algorithms in automatic design of novel magic charms}.
\end{rubric}
```

It came out like this:

[image]

Obviously, this looks super weird. I don't know how to move the logo to the left or the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: A]

To insert your school logo you need to do two things:

1. Add the package `multirow` in the preamble.

   ```
   \documentclass[a4paper,skipsamekey,11pt,english]{curve}

   \usepackage{settings}

   \RequirePackage{multirow} %<<<<<<<<<<<< added

    % Change the fonts if you want
    ...
   ```
2. Replace the original file `education.tex` for this one:

   ```
        \newcommand{\marker}{ \hspace*{1.2em}\relscale{.9}\color{MarkerColour!80!black}\faBookmark}

        \newcommand{\unilogo}{\includegraphics[width=50pt]{example-grid-100x100pt}} % <<<<<<<<<<<<  scholl /uni logo here

        \newcommand{\titleii}{% title PhD <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
            \textbf{Ph.D. Unseen University} in High Energy Magic.
                        Thesis title: \emph{Low-Cost Manual Generation in Under-Resourced Environments.}
        }

        \newcommand{\titlei}{% title MSc  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        \textbf{M.Sc.~Computer Science, Unseen} in High Energy Magic. 
        Thesis title:  \emph{Applying new algorithms in automatic}  \emph{design of novel magic charms.}
        }

        \begin{rubric}{Education}

        \begin{tabular}{@{}l @{}p{15pt} >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{4in} r}
            2009 -- 2013    &\marker    & \titleii  & \multirow{4}{*}{\unilogo}     \\
            2003 -- 2006    &\marker    & \titlei   &                               \\          
        \end{tabular}

        \end{rubric}
   ```